# Understanding why $|\beta'(s)|=|\alpha'(t)\cdot (dt/ds)| = 1$ in curve reparameterization by arc length

Tags: differential-geometry, parametrization, arc-length

I am reading Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, and I am stuck understanding why $|\beta'(s)|=|\alpha'(t)\cdot (dt/ds)| = 1$ is true.

For context, here is the paragraph where it is reparameterizing a curve $\alpha(t)$ by its arc length. I can follow all the argument, but I am stuck on the above result.

[image]

$\left|\frac{d}{ds} \beta(s)\right| = \left|\frac{d}{ds} \alpha(t(s))\right|=|\alpha'(t) \cdot t'(s)|$.

How does this equal $1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He writes that $|\alpha'(t)|=s'(t)$, and since $t(s)$ and $s(t)$ are inverses, their derivatives are related via
$$t'(s)=\frac{1}{s'(t)}.$$
Plugging this in gives $1.$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation.

Comment: (+1) but the magnitude sign around $\alpha'(t)$ seems to have gotten lost.

Comment: How is $\alpha’(t) = s’(t)$?

Comment: @Sun $s'(t)=|\alpha '(t)|$, you missed the modulus

Comment: Oh I see. That’s from the definition of arc length. When differentiated wrt t, you get the integrand back. Thanks.

Comment: Really to address what @AndrewD.Hwang said this should be $|\alpha'(t) * t'(s)| = |\alpha'(t) | * |t'(s)| = s'(t) * |t'(s)|$, but since arc length is monotonically increasing, then $|t'(s)| = t'(s)$, and since s and t are differentiable inverses of each other then $s'(t) t'(s) = 1$ for all $s \in J$.